# UK Citizen, Japanese Resident - where do I pay tax for royalties paid to UK bank?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom

I am self employed, work and reside in Japan. Most of my income gets paid vis PayPal or directly to my Japanese bank account. The exception is my  Amazon royalties that can't be paid into a Japanese account so it gets paid into my UK account.

My confusion is whether I should be paying tax on this in the UK? What about Japan?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which country / countries are you tax resident in?

Comment: Japan. 
I haven't paid anything in the UK since '98 because that is when I left...but I don't know if I supposed to!

Answer (score 1):

You are required to declare in a UK tax return any income you have earned from UK sources.  As you are not resident in the UK (and have not been for some time), you are not liable to any UK tax on your global (non-UK sourced) income.

If Amazon are paying money into a UK account, the HMRC may view this as UK sourced income - you would have to check with them.

Note that if you are still a British Citizen you are still eligible for the Personal Allowance on income, so if the amount you earn each year is small (less than 10k GBP) you probably do not owe anything.